# Green monster or something with gum or glue in the name

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember getting told a story as a kid about a green monster that jumps from house to house and kills people. I can't remember his name and I think it had glue or gum in the name.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This isn't a lot of info to go on. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and [edit your post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/166358/edit) to add any and all additional information you can remember so we can help you better.

Comment: Was it a story you were _told_? Is there any indication that it's not just a story made up by the person telling it to you? In other words, is this a story that can be _found_ by one of us?